# Jest detects open redis client on travis-ci

Tags: node.js, redis, travis-ci

I encountered some difficulties with redis testing on travis-ci.
Here is the redis setup code,

```
async function getClient() {
  const redisClient = createClient({
    socket: {
      url: redisConfig.connectionString,
      reconnectStrategy: (currentNumberOfRetries: number) => {
        if (currentNumberOfRetries > 1) {
          throw new Error("max retries reached");
        }
        return 1000;
      },
    },
  });
  try {
    await redisClient.connect();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  return redisClient;
}
```

Here is the travis config, note that I run `npm install redis` because it is listed as a peer dependency.

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "14"
dist: focal # ubuntu 20.04
services:
  - postgresql
  - redis-server
addons:
  postgresql: "13"
  apt:
    packages:
      - postgresql-13
env:
  global:
    - PGUSER=postgres
    - PGPORT=5432 # for some reason unlike what documentation says, the port is 5432
  jobs:
    - NODE_ENV=ci
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
before_install:
  - sudo sed -i -e '/local.*peer/s/postgres/all/' -e 's/peer\|md5/trust/g' /etc/postgresql/*/main/pg_hba.conf
  - sudo service postgresql restart
  - sleep 1
  - postgres --version
  - pg_lsclusters # shows port of postgresql, ubuntu specific command
install:
  - npm i
  - npm i redis
before_script:
  - sudo psql -c 'create database orm_test;' -p 5432 -U postgres
script:
  - npm run test-detectopen
```

The first issue is this missing client.connect function, whereas connection on my local machine with `redis-server` running works.

```
console.log
    TypeError: redisClient.connect is not a function
        at Object.getClient (/home/travis/build/sunjc826/mini-orm/src/connection/redis/index.ts:21:23)
        at Function.init (/home/travis/build/sunjc826/mini-orm/src/data-mapper/index.ts:33:30)
        at /home/travis/build/sunjc826/mini-orm/src/lib-test/tests/orm.test.ts:25:20
        at Promise.then.completed (/home/travis/build/sunjc826/mini-orm/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:390:28)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at callAsyncCircusFn (/home/travis/build/sunjc826/mini-orm/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:315:10)
        at _callCircusHook (/home/travis/build/sunjc826/mini-orm/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:181:40)
        at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/home/travis/build/sunjc826/mini-orm/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:47:7)
        at run (/home/travis/build/sunjc826/mini-orm/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:25:3)
        at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (/home/travis/build/sunjc826/mini-orm/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:166:21)
```

The second is this open handle issue, on my local machine, even if connection fails, jest does not give such an error and exits cleanly.

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:
  ●  TCPWRAP
       7 |
       8 | async function getClient() {
    >  9 |   const redisClient = createClient({
         |                       ^
      10 |     socket: {
      11 |       url: redisConfig.connectionString,
      12 |       reconnectStrategy: (currentNumberOfRetries: number) => {
      at RedisClient.Object.<anonymous>.RedisClient.create_stream (node_modules/redis/index.js:196:31)
      at new RedisClient (node_modules/redis/index.js:121:10)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.createClient (node_modules/redis/index.js:1023:12)
      at Object.getClient (src/connection/redis/index.ts:9:23)
      at Function.init (src/data-mapper/index.ts:33:30)
      at src/lib-test/tests/orm.test.ts:25:20
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:387:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:408:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:261:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is likely caused by redis being a peer dependency.

Listing out node-redis versions, I'm guessing the version tagged latest (as of time writing 3.1.2) was installed instead of the version 4+.

So, I moved redis to regular dependencies instead.